# Como cambiar formato de fecha timestamp a fecha de javascript?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, date, redux, calendar

estoy haciendo un calendario con react, redux, firebase y react big calendar. El problema que tengo es que no se estarian viendo los eventos en mi calendario. Mi teoria es que no se ven por el formato en que viene la fecha de los eventos desde firebase. Intente con `toDate()` y con `new Date()` para pasarlos a una fecha de javascript pero no pude.

Tambien estoy teniendo dificultades para poder acceder a las propiedades de los eventos por ejemplo si hago `console.log(events.start)` para poder traer la fecha de inicio, me arroja `undefined`

Espero que me puedan dar una mano. muchas gracias!

Link a mi repo: https://github.com/guidomora/peluqueria-new-calendar.git

Codigo de como traigo mis eventos desde firebase:

```
  const startLoadingEvents = async () => {
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "tobias"));
    const events = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      events.push({id: doc.id, ...doc.data()});
    });
    dispatch(setEvent(events))
  };
```

imagen de consola:

[image: consola]

Evento en firebase:

[image: evento firebase]

Answer (score 0):

Unos de los motivos por lo que te puede estar pasando esto es porque te estás basando en qué events no es una array:

```
const [events, setEvent] = useState ([{“start”: “example”}])
console.log(events.start)
// devolverá indefinido obligatoriamente ya que el start está dentro de events[0]
```

Comment: ya lo pude solucionar muchas gracias! en realidad era que para pasar la fecha tenia que usar event.start.toDate() en vez de toDate(event.start)